# Sending JSON objects between .NET server and Java server

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, json, sockets

I'm working on a **.NET Web Application** that uses a Database. Whenever data is changed, instead of directly updating the Database, I need to do it through a **Java Server**. That is, the Web Application has no access to the database but instead gets and sends all the information from/to the Java Server through **TCP Sockets**, which in turn handles the Database. Basically, I need to send **JSON** serialized objects from the **.NET Server** to the **Java Server** back and forth. What is the best approach to use in this situation? What **DataStreams** should I use on each side?

Comment: I would say that how you do use it is depending of how the java server is exposed to the clients, you will need to implement the contract already defined there, If what are you looking to is how to use sockets from .net, take a look to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/synchronous-client-socket-example